# ActorGestureListener Fling does not register

Tags: java, input, libgdx

I can't get my app to register a fling action on a specific actor. I have no problem when adding a simple `tap` to the actor and checking for a tap on the table. Doing the same thing for flick but it does not work. Am I missing something? Looked everywhere online and not much info on the ActorGestureListener's fling.

my Code:

```
    mainLeftTable.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
    mainLeftTable.addListener(new ActorGestureListener(){
        @Override
        public void fling(InputEvent event, float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
            System.out.println(velocityX + " - " + velocityY);
        }
    });
```

Nothing happens using this code, I can't see what I'm missing

For reference, setting up `tap` works with this code:

```
    mainLeftTable.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
    mainLeftTable.addListener(new ActorGestureListener(){
        @Override
        public void tap(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int count, int button) {
            System.out.println("tapped");
        }
```

I have my stage as the input processor.

**Update:**

Apparently it is something in ScrollPane that messes it up, if I disable the ScrollPane on my table, the fling works. Why is this? I need the scroll

Answer (score 1):

Are you telling the Gdx app about the listener? that is, calling:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(yourListener)
```

to tell the app about your new listener? And if you have multiple listeners, you'll likely need to use an InputMultiplexer. Not sure how the rest of your code is setup with your "tap" listener.

I did a quick search and ran across the following tutorial which may give an example you can repurpose to your code:

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/10/24/LibGDX-Tutorial-5-Handling-Input-Touch-and-gestures.aspx

Edit:

Based on the comments, here is a sample app that works. I think this is what you're trying to do.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Touchable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ActorGestureListener;

public class Fling implements ApplicationListener {
   private Texture music;
   private SpriteBatch batch;
   private OrthographicCamera camera;
   private Stage stage;

   @Override
   public void create() {
      camera = new OrthographicCamera();
      camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
      batch = new SpriteBatch();

      music = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("img/sprites/buttons/music_off.png"));
      Image image = new Image(music);
      Table actor = new Table();
      actor.debug();
      actor.add(image).width(105).height(105);
      actor.setX(100);
      actor.setY(100);
      actor.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
      actor.addListener(new ActorGestureListener(){
          @Override
          public void fling(InputEvent event, float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
              System.out.println(velocityX + " - " + velocityY);
          }

          @Override
          public void tap(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int count, int button) {
              System.out.println("tapped");
          }

          @Override
          public void touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
              System.out.println("touchdown");
          }           

      });
      stage = new Stage();
      stage.addActor(actor);

      Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
   }

   @Override
   public void render() {
       stage.draw();
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose() {
      music.dispose();
      batch.dispose();
   }

   @Override
   public void resize(int width, int height) {
   }

   @Override
   public void pause() {
   }

   @Override
   public void resume() {
   }
```

}

And when I run it, I see:
[image: working fling]

Comment: The thing is, I should not need to when adding the listener like this. Im very aware of how to set an inputProcesser and/or multiplexer. But since every other action works, I feel like I'm missing something else, its just "fling" that does nothing.

Comment: OK, thanks for adding the extra code&clarification. I've used the GestureAdapter before, not the ActorGestureListener, and had no issues with fling. I tried a few things here but couldn't replicate your setup. Unless you want to post some more code, I'll let others take a crack at answering.

Comment: Thanks for trying man. I don't know what other code is relevant. Unfortunately I can't use GestureAdapter like this, then I'd have to go with a multiplexer like you said. Which I might, but wanted to see if there was something else I could do :)

Comment: odd, I scrapped what I was doing earlier and created a barebones class that implements Application Listener, copy+pasted your code for the ActorGestureListener, and all works fine - touch/tap/fling - I see your println's. No gesture adapter. Only the stage as input processor. I only joined SO couple days ago. Not sure what the etiquette or best practice is. I have ~80 lines of code and screenshot to show a working version, but not sure if that helps you or not.

Comment: Id love if you posted ur working solution. Maybe I can find something I missed :)

Comment: Turns out ScrollPane causes the problem. Dont know why. Need the ScrollPane so guess Im tucked.,

Comment: Tried to comment on your updated question, but I don't have enough rep yet. Wild guess, but ScrollPane implements its own ActorGestureListener for "flickScrollListener". I wonder if this supersedes/interferes with your ActorGestureListener that you're trying to implement on your table. Maybe if you call scrollPane.setFlickScroll(false) it may help? (Just wild-a$$-guessing at this point, though)

Comment: I created my own little solution, it requires me to check for scroll.velocityX() in every frame but only one I could think of. setting setFlickScroll to false also means I could not scroll without touching the scroll-bar anymore, which is really not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after checking the source code for the ScrollPane, I noticed that the ActorGestureListener already handles the fling event and automatically cancels the touch focus.

Simply call setCancelTouchFocus(false) on your ScrollPane and you will be able to handle the fling event yourself. At least this solved the problem for me.